# Golang chromedp dockerfile

Tags: go, dockerfile, chromedp

I have a golang code that uses chromedp to connect to the user's local chrome
here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    Api := gin.Default()

    Api.GET("api/jwt", func(c *gin.Context) {
        opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
            chromedp.Flag("headless", false),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-gpu", true),
            chromedp.Flag("no-sandbox", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-dev-shm-usage", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-browser-side-navigation", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-infobars", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-extensions", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-notifications", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-default-apps", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-background-timer-throttling", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows", true),
            chromedp.Flag("disable-renderer-backgrounding", true),
        )

        allocCtx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
        defer cancel()

        ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(allocCtx)
        defer cancel()

        var localStorageData string // Declaração da variável localStorageData

        err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
            chromedp.Navigate("https://csonlinetenant.b2clogin.com/csonlinetenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
            chromedp.Sleep(5*time.Second),
            chromedp.WaitVisible(`#fgh`),
            chromedp.SendKeys(`#fghfg`, "fghfgh"),
            chromedp.SendKeys(`#xcvxcv`, "xcxcvcxv"),
            chromedp.Click(`#thgh`, chromedp.ByID),
            chromedp.Sleep(5*time.Second),
            chromedp.Click(`dfgd`, chromedp.ByID),
            chromedp.Sleep(15*time.Second),
            chromedp.EvaluateAsDevTools(`localStorage.getItem('c')`, &localStorageData),
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("Bearer", localStorageData)

        // Restante do código...

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "Success": localStorageData,
        })
    })

    listenAddr := os.Getenv("LISTEN")

    if val, ok := os.LookupEnv("FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT"); ok {
        listenAddr = ":" + val
    }
    if listenAddr == "" {
        listenAddr = ":8080"
    }

    Api.Run(listenAddr)
}
```

so i made a dockerfile which contains what i need for my clients to use this application (i installed chrome and built my golang in the image)

dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.20 AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

# Instale as dependências do Chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
RUN chrome &


COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /dockergo

# Run the tests in the container
FROM build-stage AS run-test-stage
RUN go test -v ./...

# Deploy the application binary into a lean image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11 AS build-release-stage

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build-stage /dockergo /dockergo

EXPOSE 8080

USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/dockergo"]
```

the image builds successfully and without a headache
but when testing the docker image in my local I get this error:

```
 Error: exec: "google-chrome": executable file not found in $PATH
```

what does this error mean? that my chrome is not running? how can i run it?

Comment: It doesn't look like your code attempts to connect to the users local chrome. It installs google-chrome-stable inside the container, and fails to start it for some reason. Here's the PATH-lookup logic https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/blob/f468fe96718b2edb1c28d22c351cd7c96834b3a4/allocate.go#L349 . google-chrome-stable should be in /user/bin - make sure /usr/bin is in PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome browser is installed in the `build-stage` only. It's not available in the final image that is created by the `build-release-stage`.

I tried to install Chrome with this Dockerfile:

```
# Deploy the application binary into a lean image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11 AS build-release-stage

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
RUN chrome &
```

But it failed with this message:

```
...
Step 2/4 : RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -     && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
 ---> Running in 7596202a5684
failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I think you have to choose another base image on which it is easy to install Chrome. A better alternative is to use `chromedp/headless-shell` as the base image. This image contains Chrome's headless shell, which is very small. The demo Dockerfile below also shows compiling the test binary first and then run the test in the `chromedp/headless-shell` image:

```
FROM golang:1.20.5-buster AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o dockergo
# Build the test binary
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go test -c -o dockergo.test

# Run the tests in the container
FROM chromedp/headless-shell:114.0.5735.199 AS run-test-stage

WORKDIR /app
# Copy other files that is needed to run the test (testdata?).
COPY . .
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dockergo.test ./dockergo.test
RUN /app/dockergo.test -test.v

# Deploy the application binary into a lean image
FROM chromedp/headless-shell:114.0.5735.199 AS build-release-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dockergo /dockergo

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/dockergo"]
```